# why is my stringstream giving me empty when i have already printed out the contents of my object to console

Tags: string, c++11, stringstream

I have overloaded the [<< operator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpQlv.png). I tried printing out the object in my main class and it looks perfect. The problem is when I try to pass that object to stringstream, the string stream object gives me empty.

[stringstream printing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x320.png)

Comment: Please your `TimeSpan` class code

Comment: Please post code *in the question*. Firstly, so that others can cut and paste it into an IDE and secondly so that it has the same life-time as the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator<<(ostream& output, ...)` ignores its `output` parameter, and always prints to `std::cout`. `output` stream is left unchanged (except when it happens to also refer to `std::cout`).